Why are there redundant slashes in comment headers in c or c++ "*//**"
I often see:
/**************************************************************************//**
 * some comments
 *****************************************************************************/

Why not:
/*****************************************************************************
 * some comments
 *****************************************************************************/

As I understand doxygen requires special comments to  process it (see: Documenting the code). But it also has the option to enable JAVADOC_BLOCK in doxyfile. Why compromise the aesthetics of code when it's not needed? You can choose to add doxygen commands to those blocks too or leave them out if you want.
Edit:
I get unexpected behavior when checking JAVADOC_BLOCK, but unchecking JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF. It still autobriefs.

If the JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF tag is set to YES then doxygen will interpret the
first line (until the first dot) of a Javadoc-style comment as the brief
description. If set to NO, the Javadoc-style will behave just like regular Qt-
style comments (thus requiring an explicit @brief command for a brief
description.)[emphasis mine]

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * \file a.c
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * javadoc header without brief
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
void a(void)
{
}  

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * \brief javadoc header with brief
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
void b(void)
{    
}
  
  
/**************************************************************************//**
 *
 * doxystyle header without brief
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
void c(void)
{    
} 
 
/**************************************************************************//**
 *
 * \brief doxystyle header with brief
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
void d(void)
{    
} 
 
int main(void)
{
    a();
    b();
    c();
    d();
    return 0;
}

In doxygen-1.11.0 a and c autobrief
Edit2:
I guess doxygen cannot be configured the way I want it. I'm forced to use their aestheticially unpleasing comment styles. The best improvement I could make is to use this (notice the asterisks at the end align now):
/*************************************************************************//**
 * some comments
 *****************************************************************************/


So you have case 1: /**  some comment .... In my opinion your second part is common used in code, e.g. licenses, copyright, but also on other places) which were not mean to be doxygen parts. Just important legacy. But just guesses

The answer is simple, the developers either don't know about the setting, or can't be bothered to set it.

Even better:  Drop the waste-of-time " My God!  It's full of stars! " comments and use a simple /** line to start your Doxygen or Javadoc documentation.

The developer might want to use some fancy comment blocks that will be ignored by Doxygen by setting JAVADOC_BANNER = NO.

One could also ask the question: why should I dig into Doxygen options when I can simply replace two asterisks with two slashes? :) (The "aesthetics of code" ventures into subjective territory. Not everyone is forced to agree with your assessment..)

@JaMiT I agree aesthetics can be subjective. But in this case it is objectively less clean/consistent and breaks convention. I personally do not like the Christmaslights headers, but if I use them I want them to be clean. It is also about convenience. Modifying comment style just so the tool sees it when it's not needed.

@elechris "But in this case it is objectively less clean/consistent" -- to a trivial and easily ignored extent, hence the concern could be insignificant to someone -- "and breaks convention" -- Not if your convention is to use this style. It's still a subjective call.

Sometimes one wants to put a big separator comment in the source code just to break the source code up.
For example, if you have a collection of related structures (or c++ classes) in a single header file (because you like big header files), you might consider inserting a big banner comment that tells the reader that "This is the main class", or "these are all the internal structures". Remember that in c you don't have the same flexibility to hide utility structures inside the objects that use them.
You just don't want that comment to go into the generated documentation file if it will add nothing to the documentation.
Other times, you want the big banner style in the file, but then you decide you do want the content in the generated documentation file, because it has added some value. Sometimes this is a later editorial decision.
Of course, you can also use javadoc tags to generate sections in the documentation which you could use to collate related internal structures, and you could use the existing banners to do that - or not, it is a choice, sometimes born out of not wanting to overcomplicate the generated documentation.
The  /***************************// trick lets you choose on an individual basis to promote some banners to the documentation, while ignoring most of them, and not reformatting your source file too much.

"You just don't want that comment to go into the generated documentation file if it will add nothing to the documentation." I just tested it and found that even if I uncheck JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF it will still autobrief javadoc if I check JAVADOC_BANNER. You think there is a way to not autobrief javadoc? I updated my question with the example. Because if there is a way to not autobrief, then I don't see the issue.

The Doxygen documentation you linked actually contains the answer (showing the exact style that you mentioned):


Some people like to make their comment blocks more visible in the documentation. For this purpose, you can use the following:

    /********************************************//**
     *  ... text
     ***********************************************/

Note: the 2 slashes to end the normal comment block and start a
special comment block.
Note: be careful when using a reformatter like clang-format as it may
see this type of comment as 2 separate comments and introduce spacing
between them.

(emphasis is mine)
So to answer your question, it is not really needed, but some people use it to make their comment blocks more visible in the documentation.

Update:
It turned out the Doxygen documentation above does not really give a good rationale for the 2 slashes.  They are added to turn the comment into a Doxygen comment, but there is a better way to do it:
Add the JAVADOC_BANNER flag, and then you can use the following cleaner version (without the slashes) which is not less visible:
/************************************************
 *  ... text
 ***********************************************/

This means the answer to your question is the one given in @HolyBlackCat's comment above:
The reason for the strange style with 2 slashes is that the developers either don't know about the setting, or can't be bothered to set it.

the slashes don't make it more visible so it doesn't answer my question

"To make it move visible" is the answer to "why a bunch of * instead of nothing". While OP is asking something else, they ask "why ****//** instead of ***** when you can make the latter work by enabling a doxygen setting".

@HolyBlackCat the doxygen documentation gives this exact example including the 2 slashes near the end, as an example of making the comment more visible. It even mentions the 2 slashes explicitly in the note. Please see the documentation link. What did I miss ?

The docs don't say that // makes the comment more visible. A bunch of *s makes it more visible. // at the end just turns it into a valid doxygen comment. The question is why use those // when you could allow those comments with a doxygen flag as well.

@HolyBlackCat I finally see your point. I am not a doxygen expert and so missed it initially. I think the doxygen documentation is a little confusing on this issue. I added an update to the answer.

"but some people use it to make their comment blocks more visible in the documentation." -- Not quite. Some people use it either 1) to make the documentation source more visible in the code or 2) to make the highly-visible comment do double-duty as a source for Doxygen-generated documentation. Depends on your point of view. In any event, the visibility in the documentation is not affected. (In fact, the whole point of this trick is to get Doxygen to skip over most of the first row of asterisks.)
